# Should a function lookup data or retrieve it?

Tags: architecture, structure, conventions

I am building a service that fetches data from a database and provides methods and properties to compute and show the data.

When initializing, the data is stored on property of the service. It also holds a private method that loops through the data, counting items with a specific property.

When this private method is called, I pass the data as an argument:

`myPrivateFunction(this.data);`

However, I thought about renaming the `data` property. Doing so will force me to rename each argument at each call aswell. (Assume I am using an IDE that is not capable of doing this automatically).

If the function would retrieve the data by itself, I could avoid this. Yet, it would be less convienent to enable this, as the data lives outside the private method's scope.

I wonder if there are any rules or conventions about whether a function should retrieve data to work with by itself or by argument?

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to pass data as an argument because it makes clear what the function does and it allows easily track the flow of the data. I agree that it could be difficult to maintain all these arguments if you add a new one. To make changes easier you can use objects instead of list of arguments. This technique is especially useful if you pass objects across multiple layers of the application. Then you have to change only the first and the last function (in function chain) if you add a new property to the object.